# Is it possible to increase the amount of Powerplay Contracts you can recieve in Elite: dangerous?

Tags: elite-dangerous

Like the title says, I would like to know if it is possible to increase the amount of powerplay contracts you can receive in one go, because a mere 10 contracts seems like a small amount!
Thanks,
CMDR Coopmac

Answer (score 2):

If you navigate to Navigation > Galactic Powers > Rating, you'll notice your Pledge Rating tab and Available Ratings tab.

Your Pledge Rating tab displays the Rating you have with the Power your allied with. Your Available Ratings tab displays what benefit each Rating supplies you with.

You increase your Rating by meeting the Merit requirements for each one.

In accordance with your Rating you'll see how many power commodities each Rating is allowed access to. For example, Rating 1 with the Edmund Mahon allows for 10 power commodities, Rating 2 allows for 15, Rating 3 for 20, Rating 4 for 25, and Rating 5 for 50.